# Dataframe row replication with condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like below:-

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {
            'id': [1,1,1],
            'session': [12,13,14],
            'month': [1,2,3],
            'pct_churn': [0,0,1],

            }

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,
                  columns=pd.Index(['id', 'session', 'month', 'pct_churn']))

print(df)
```

[image]

The desired output of the DF is below:-

[image]

Logic:-

1.)Each row will be replicated 12 times (12 months).

2.) If the churn is in the third month then the first two months for the first id will be 0 and then 1.

3.) For the second row again it will be replicated 12 times and the churn for the first month will be 0 and then for the rest of the months will be 1.

4.) same for the third row as well but the pct_churn will be 1 for all the month.

5.) for session 13 2nd month will be the first months and for session 14 the third month will be its first month.

I am stuck here for a while please let me know if I am not explaining the problem properly.

Comment: Your 2nd row (excl. title) of output doesn't match Logic 2). According to your description, it should have `pct_churn=0`, right?

Comment: How it's not matching. for session 12 the first two months are zero, for session 13 just the first month is 0 and for session 14 none of them are zero

Comment: This is what I understand: According to Logic 2), the churn of session 12 happens at month 1. So session 12 should have zeros up to month 1 and the rest are 1s. Same, the churn of session 13 happens at month 2, so the month 1 and 2 should be zero and otherwise 1 (also unmatched). Session 14 has churn=1 so all months are 1 (matched).

Comment: This is a monthly subscription thing...I am sorry for the confusion. so, first, we will replicate each row for 12 times (12 months). Now for session 12 the first and 2nd month are zero so starting 3rd month it will be 1(pct_change.) for session 13 end month willbe the first month so after first month it will be 1 and fopr session 14 the 3rd month will be its first month and in this since beginning the pct_churn is 1

Comment: You did not explain why are the churn values for row 1 and row 2 NOT 0 and 0 respectively. They seemed like 3 and 2 (or 2 and 1) respectively by some logic I don't really understand from your description. Especially for session 13, why there is only one zero value instead of the previous 2? I don't understand where the decrement comes from.

Comment: because for session 13 month 2 will be the first month and 3rd will be the 2nd and so on. and for 14 the third will be the first month